# How can i install openssl lcrypto in my mac

Tags: terminal, openssl, linker, pip, linker-errors

I have been trying to install open-event-server fossasia on my mac.
I have been gettin this error for a while.I have updated my pip and tried to reinstall the openssl.
Still it persist.
Help me!
Attaching the screenshot of my terminal.

[image]

Link to image-:

Answer (score 0):

try this

`cd /usr/local/include`

`ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl`

In the `open-event-server` repo root:

`rm -rf _build`

`CFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" make rel`

quoted from [raflr](https://github.com/ralfr) in this [issue](https://github.com/vernemq/vernemq/issues/206)

Comment: glad i was helpful to you